# name error:name 'wav_filename' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, audio, wav

> name 'wav_filename' is not defined

```
def Text2Speech(file_name,InpText):
    Mp3Extension=".mp3"
    waveExtension=".wav"
    mp3FilePath="C:\\Texttospeech\\"+file_name+Mp3Extension
    waveFilePath="C:\\Texttospeech\\"+file_name+waveExtension
    if os.path.isfile(waveFilePath):
        PlaySound(waveFilePath);
    else:
        tts=gTTS(text=InpText,lang="en-us")
        tts.save(mp3FilePath)
        f = TemporaryFile();
        tts.write_to_fp(f);
        f.close();
        subprocess.call(['C:\\Temp\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg', '-i', mp3FilePath,mp3FilePath])
        PlaySound(waveFilePath);

    return;
def PlaySound (wavFile) :
    chunk = 1024
    try:
        wf = wave.open(wavFile, 'rb')
    except IOError as ioe:
        sys.stderr.write('IOError on file ' + wav_filename + '\n' + \
        str(ioe) + '. Skipping.\n')
        return
    except EOFError as eofe:
        sys.stderr.write('EOFError on file ' + wav_filename + '\n' + \
        str(eofe) + '. Skipping.\n')
        return
    # Instantiate PyAudio.
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    stream = p.open(
        format = p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
        channels = wf.getnchannels(),
        rate = wf.getframerate(),
        output = True)
    data = wf.readframes(chunk)

    while len(data) > 0:
        stream.write(data)
        data = wf.readframes(chunk)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wav_filename` was not defined in the function `PlaySound`.

Comment: But i have defined it there or where should i define in playsound?